# Set population field validation in masked text box

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, currency, maskedtextbox

Hi I am new to C# I have one problem in `masked text box`

Population range is 1,000 to 12,00,00,00,000

My problem is when enter 1000 in masked text box it will be taken as 1,000 like when i enter 12000 it will considered as 12,000 like default it will arranged in `,`.

How can i do it? Please provide if any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `Mask` property set to? Try making it: `#,##0`.